# selectizeInput doesn't work on my shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I've written a shiny application which works just fine locally. However, when I upload it to shiny server (hosted on my server), the `selectizeInput` widgets don't appear anymore. You can see it [here](http://www.joelgombin.fr:3838/shiny/LireMinInterieur/).

I've tried including the file `selectize.min.js` in the `www` folder, but it doesn't seem to help.

Any idea what may be going wrong?

BTW, I'm using shiny 0.9.1 and shiny server v1.1.0.10000 (under an Ubuntu 12.04 server)

Comment: As an additional piece of information, it also works on `shinyapps.io`, even though it throws an alert (due to encoding issue, I think): see [https://gombin.shinyapps.io/LireMinInterieur/](https://gombin.shinyapps.io/LireMinInterieur/).

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example. Does `selectizeInput` work on shiny server for this minimal reproducible example. Otherwise you are asking us to audit your externally hosted code.

Comment: @jdharrison thanks for forcing me to do a MRE, it actually put me on the way towards the solution (even though that was a rather long path!).

Comment: its often like that lol. Glad your problem is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, I finally found the solution, [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/nQBGjm6UGrM).

The problem was that the shiny server locale was only `C`, even though the locale for the server in general was `fr_FR.UTF-8`. So i had to add the following line to `server.R` (I also added it to `ui.R`, by security).

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.UTF-8")
```

Now it works juts fine!